# How to remove child of horizontalview in android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I faced not delete child inside the horizontalview. if already have child of horizontalview then delete or remove and if not child then addview. please see code, what i did. but why this not working.

Result: it append previous view in horizontall layout.

```
first time:
Horizontalview
1 4 7

second time
Horizontalview
1 4 7 6 0 7 8
```

but i want

```
second time
Horizontalview
 6 0 7 8

third time
Horizontalview
 2 9 5
```

my code

```
   if(horizontalScrollview.getChildCount()>0){
        horizontalScrollview.removeAllViews();
        horizontalScrollview.addView(dataLayout);
    }else {
        horizontalScrollview.addView(dataLayout);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HorizantalScrollView` contains only one `child view` , that child may `add` or `remove` child `views`,  try this:

```
if (horizontalScrollview.getChildCount() > 0) {
            horizontalScrollview.removeAllViews();
            horizontalScrollview.addView(dataLayout);
        } else {
            horizontalScrollview.addView(dataLayout);
        }
```

to

```
    ViewGroup parentLayout = (ViewGroup) horizontalScrollview.getChildAt(0);

    if (parentLayout.getChildCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parentLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            parentLayout.removeView(parentLayout.getChildAt(i));
        }
    } else {
        parentLayout.addView(dataLayout);
    }
```