# removeAllViews in HorizontalScrollView does not remove views

Tags: android, baseadapter, horizontalscrollview

I am getting few crashes because of this code: (I never got a crash on my devices)
The crash is:java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Here is the code (I added a try and catch to make sure that this is the code causing the problem):

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
        LinearLayout newView = getItem(position).getNewView();
        HorizontalScrollView hv = (HorizontalScrollView)view.findViewById(R.id.s_scrollview);
        hv.removeAllViews();
        if(newView != null){
            try {
                hv.addView(newView);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace(); 
// I also send a remote crash log here that is how I confirmed that the crash it is here. I never get a crash on my devices
            }
        }
    ...
    }
```

This is very frustrating. Anybody have a clue on what is wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Look this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917329/how-to-remove-child-of-horizontalview-in-android

Comment: @Diego I don't want to add multiple views. I want to remove all views and add a single one. Is it wrong my approach? (I am looking to find the fastest way to do this because as you can see it is inside of a getView and runs on UI)

Comment: Where is `newView` coming from? Maybe that is the child that already has a parent?

Comment: newView comes from an object and it is a LinearLayout

Comment: Well, I'm if I'm reading the exception correctly the problem is that newView already has a parent. So you have to remove the view from the parent. You can try to do this:      `((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(newView);`. But maybe im misreading it.

Comment: @mrtn No, I think you are perfectly right.

Comment: Ok, I changed the answer, so if someone else has the same problem finds it easier. If that solved your question, it would be kind if you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that newView already has a parent. The exception says that first the parent should remove its child. That would look like that:

```
if(newView != null){
    ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(newView);
    hv.addView(newView);
}
```

Comment: Mea culpa. newView comes from an object and it is a LinearLayout